# Delete folders with ^M inside name

Tags: bash

On linux a buggy script created folders with this : ^M at the end of the name.
The ^M is moved to ? with a ls -al.

A search on the ? is not working as a search on ^M (or ^M)

How can I remove these folders?

Comment: If the directory is empty, `rmdir *$'\r'` will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is use a c-style string where you can specify the `^M` or Carriage Return characters with its backslash escape `\r`.

A c-style string is made of `$` and single-quotes: `$'a c-style string'`

Find the bugged directories:

```sh
find . -type d -name $'*\r'
```

List the bugged directory names:

```sh
ls -d *$'\r'
```

Rename the bugged directories by removing the trailing CR.

```sh
find . -type d -name $'*\r' -execdir sh -c $'for d; do mv -- "$d" "${d%\r}"; done' _ {} +
```

Delete the faulty named directories in current directory, with their content:

```sh
rm -r -- *$'\r'
```